# Accessing marshmallow decorators when using flask-marshmallow

Tags: python, flask-restful, marshmallow

I'm using flask-restful, flask-sqlalchemy and flask-marshmallow to build an API service. I define the following -

```
ma = Marshmallow(app)
```

However, trying to access the @validates decorator using ma throws an error.

```
@ma.validates('field1')
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it better to directly use the marshmallow library and skip using flask-marshmallow altogether?

Comment: Put the traceback of error that you got. And also `flask-marshmallow` doesn't have `validate()` decorator.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to reach `flask-marshmallow` decorators in its API, however there is none.

So you to understand if you need `flask-marshmallow` package, or only `marshmallow` is required.

Also to make things work, you need to use [`validates()`](http://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference.html#marshmallow.decorators.validates) decorator as it presented in docs

```
@validates('field1')
```